# Make mouse cursor remain the same when panel refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I make the mouse cursor remain the same pointer when I use a timer to refresh a panel every five seconds?

Now it very briefly changes to a loading cursor every five seconds. It is really distracting.

Comment: There are various techniques to check for updates in the background (via javascript) rather than forcing a page reload. Too many for a single answer here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like setting `Cursor.Current` to the `Arrow` or any other kind of cursor that you want. You might be able to put this in your `Tick` event on your timer.

```
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Comment: Impressive trick if you can get that to run on the client side for an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the tag.